# How to determine the order of the poles of this particular function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $$f(z) := \frac{1}{z^{2n}+1} \quad .$$
The denominator is equal to zero when $z^{2n} = -1$, so its zeros $z_{k}$ are located at $z_{k} = e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}+\frac{k \pi i}{n}} $. These are the poles of $f$.

I would like to know what the order of these poles is, and how to calculate them. I can't figure it out by means of the definition of a pole of order $m$.

I suppose the poles are of order $1$, since they're all located on a different place on the unit circle.

Comment: All the zeroes of $g(z)=z^{2n}-1$ are simple since $g'(z)=2n z^{2n-1}$ vanishes only in $0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please show me how this relates to the order of the poles? What result links the derivative of the function in the denominator to the poles?

Comment: The order of the pole of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ in $z=z_0$ is just the order of the zero of $f(z)$ in $z=z_0$.